# Board Updating problems

Tags: esp8266

I have updated Arduino AVR Boards in IDE and before I updated, ESP8266 boards were working, now after I updated, it says "Error downloading "URL for esp"" and no matter which website I listed inside the preference:

```
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases/download/2.3.0/package_esp8266com_index.json
```

None of them are being downloaded and I cannot program ESP8266. Can I get some help? Thank you.

Comment: what? what is "updating AVR"? what is "updating esp8266"? and when do you get the "Error downloading"?

Comment: Ok, inside the Arduino IDE, when you go to tools > boards > boards manager, this is where I updated Arduino AVR boards like geniuno, nano, etc. And I have no idea when I said "update esp8266" so I wasn't sure if you were reading or not. Also the error shows up when I open boards manager. Like after the board manager loads, thats when I get an error, so it saying  ESP8266 error downloading via the website url.

Comment: ok. now I understand the question. the missing information was "in IDE" or "package". try it without the github link in Additional boards URLs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 10 try installing from git followimg the instruction here.

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

That was how I get it to work when I found updating it through the ide didn't work